# How to change menu items on action bar when fragment changes

Tags: android, android-actionbar, items

I developed a navigation drawer which has number of fragment,s and action bar. I want to know items on action bar change when i change the fragment .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#ActionBar) you can do that

**First:**
 Create a menu file for fragment

**Second:**
 `onCreate()` method of Fragment set `setHasOptionsMenu(true);`

**Third:**
 Override `onCreateOptionsMenu`, where you'll inflate the fragment's menu and attach it to your standard menu.

**Fourth:**
Override `onOptionItemSelected` in your fragment for item handlers.

Comment: ..thnks for ans..i want to know one more thing .in my actionbar there is already a no of items ..how i can remove them when call to a specific fragment and want to show only that fragment ,s Item that i have inflate through menu of that fragment

Comment: on each fragment you have to pass a xml file contains item for that action bar.

Comment: can u give me some exp @Murtaza Hussain

Comment: the step above are example in itself.

Answer (score 0):

you can access your menu items once you have set up "on create Options Menu as follows

```
 override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_collections_new, menu)

        val menuItem2:MenuItem=menu.findItem(R.id.men_item2)
        menuItem2.title="new title2"
        

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)



    }/
```

Cheers...

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this

```
// declare a menu object at the top of the activity
Menu AppMenu;

// instantiate the AppMenu instance in the activity’s 
onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
// with code similar to:
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.myMenuLayout, menu); 
AppMenu = menu;
    return true;
}
// declare a menu object at the top of the activity
Menu AppMenu;

// instantiate the AppMenu instance in the activity’s 
onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
// with code similar to:
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.myMenuLayout, menu);
AppMenu = menu;
    return true;
}

// in the button click handler or menu item code, switch the title as 
needed
AppMenu.findItem(R.id.menuitem_expense_accept).setTitle("Expenses");// or 
“Accept”


// in the button click handler or menu item code, switch the title as 
needed
AppMenu.findItem(R.id.menuitem_expense_accept).setTitle("Expenses");// or 
“Accept”
```